# Why pyqt5 QThread which run pybind11 c++ lib still hang my main GUI?

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt5, pybind11

In my `PyQt5` program, I want to start a new thread running some code:

```
class SlamThread(QThread):
    """docstring for SlamThread"""
    def __init__(self, parent):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)

    def setSlam(self, params):
        self.params = params

    def run(self):
        self.slam = Slam()
        self.slam.setParams(self.params)
        self.slam.start()
```

Where the `Slam` is written in C++ and converted by pybind11.

And in my main program, the code is triggered by a `qAction` button:

```
def startSlam(self, ...):
        params = ...
        self.thread = SlamThread(self)
        self.thread.setSlam(params)
        self.thread.start()

        for i in range(10):
            print('done')
```

Strange thing is that it did indeed started a new thread, `done` is printed before my `Slam` progrom. However, when `Slam` started, the whole program hangs until `Slam` finished.

In my C++ `Slam` code, it is like this

```
int Slam::start()
{
    init();
    ...
    startSlam();
    return 0;
}
```

where `startSlam` takes few mins to run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://pybind11.readthedocs.io/en/stable/advanced/misc.html#global-interpreter-lock-gil) when the object is executed in a thread you must call gil_scoped_release and gil_scoped_acquire:

```cpp
int Slam::start(){
    pybind11::gil_scoped_release release;
    init();
    // ...
    pybind11::gil_scoped_acquire acquire;
    return 0;
}
```

Or in the binding:

```cpp
pybind11::class_<Slam>(mymodule, "Slam")
      .def(pybind11::init<>())
      .def("setParams", &Slam::setParams)
      .def("start", &Slam::start, pybind11::call_guard<pybind11::gil_scoped_release>());
```

<sub>You can find the complete test [here](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/55945085)</sub>

Comment: Bravo! thank you so much. It's absolutely correct. And I didn't expect that you also coded an example for me. So nice of you! @eyllanesc